# Uniform Closure of Laurent Polynomials' Algebra on $]0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

In a supplement to Rudin's "Principle of Mathematical Analysis" I am asked to deduce the following proposition:

> The uniform closure of the Algebra of complex-valued (meaning with complex coeffients) Laurent Polynomials on $]0,1]$, denoted by $L(]0,1])$, is not an algebra.

**My attempt**

So far, I have been able to prove that the limit function of any uniformly convergent sequence of Laurent Polynomials on $]0,1]$ is the sum of a continuous function and of a negative-exponent Laurent Polynomial on $]0,1]$. However, from this and the fact that a negative-exponent Laurent Polynomial on $]0,1]$ is itself a continuous function, I deduced that the closure of $L(]0,1])$ is actually the same as the algebra of continuous functions on $]0,1]$.

**My question**

Is my reasoning correct and if so, is there an error in the request of the exercise?

**Edit**

The comment by **Dark Magician** below gave me the following idea for a counter-example. Consider the functions $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$, $g(x) = 1/x$ for every $x \in ]0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, there exists a sequence of polynomials (and, hence, of Laurent Polynomials) converging to $f$ on $]0,1]$ by the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, while $g$ itself is a Laurent Polynomial. Therefore $f,g \in L(]0,1])$, however $h(x) = (fg)(x) = sin(1/x)$ for every $x \in ]0,1]$ can not be the uniform limit of any sequence of Laurent Polynomials. To see this we need an easily verifiable lemma:

> If $\{L_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of Laurent Polynomials on $]0,1]$, then, provided $L^+_n$ and $L^-_n$ denote the sequence of non-negative and negative exponent parts of $L_n$, $L_n^-$ is eventually constant and $L_n^+$ converges uniformly on $]0,1]$.

implying that any uniform limit function of a sequence of Laurent Polynomials on $]0,1]$ either converge or diverge to $\infty$ as $x \to 0$ depending on wether the sequence of non-negative exponent parts is eventually $0$ or not. However, $h$ oscillates as $x \to 0$, thus proving that $L(]0,1])$ is not an $\Bbb R$-algebra.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: @DarkMagician You are absolutely right! However I am asked to answer this question without using the concept of power series and I am now working on an example that should be satisfactory.